# bad URL Connection Error

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am at my wits end with this one.  I am attempting to make a connection to a website database.  The URL I am using is: "https://subdomain.domain.com/scripts/script.php?v=YES&userid=xxxxxxxxxx&aid=yyyy&msg=test message"

Prior to sending the URL I encode the string as follows:

```
    NSString *strURL = [url stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    url = [url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
```

When I attempt to connect to the server I get the following error message:

NSLocalizedDescription = "bad URL";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1000 \"bad URL\" UserInfo=0xa11d760 {NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on.  Here are some of the actions I have taken to troubleshoot:

1. I have tested other URLs in the app encoded the same way and have no problem.
2. I entered the URL directly in Safari, Google and Mozilla with success.
3. When I tested the URL with curl in the Terminal I discovered the key-value pairs in the query where not being assigned, for example userid was null.
4. When I pasted escaped text into the curl command line the result was successful.

I do not know what to do here.  Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Spaces aren't the only characters that need to be escaped.  Do you have any other special chars in the URL?

Comment: No, there are no other special characters in the string

Comment: A few minutes ago I again tested the url in curl, this time enclosing the url in quotes.  The connection was successful.  I would think the NSURL function would take care of this.  But, do I need to add quotes around the url?

Comment: Is it regarding the 's' - secure connection with the http which is causing the trouble?

Comment: I don't believe so.  All of the other URLs in the app have https and work fine.  I have also tried to connect with http with no success.

Comment: Can you replace " " with "+" instead of %20? Something like this:     url = [url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem -- seems the URL set to the connection was not escaped properly.  I passed the wrong string value to the method.  As you can see in the code I passed URL instead of strURL.

Thanks for your help!